# int(str) of a huge number

Tags: python, python-3.x

if i have a number that is too big to be represented with 64 bits so i receive a string that contains it.
what happens if i use:

```
num = int(num_str)
```

i am asking because it looks like it works accurately and i dont understand how, does is allocate more memory for that?

i was required to check if a huge number is a power of 2. someone suggested:

```
def power(self, A):
    A = int(A)
    if A == 1:
        return 0
    x =bin(A)
    if x.count('1')>1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

while i understand why under regular circumstances it would work, the fact that the numbers are much larger than 2^64 and it still works baffles me.

Comment: This is due to [Python's arbitrary-precision implementation for integers](https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/#:~:text=Generally%2C%20In%20languages%20like%20C,are%20represented%20as%20a%20bignum.) which allows Python to support integers of any size.

Comment: @Booboo you should have posted it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @agcala Okay, I did.

Comment: Most computers nowadays have 32bit / 64bit (or multiple thereof) registers and commandsets able to add/sub/mul 64bit (or even 4*64bit registers) in one cycle. C/C#/Java/... all use 8bit/16bit/32/bit/64bit sized numbers as "base type" so their computations can leverage these special-bitty operations.  But languages also have "bigger sized" integerstypes (f,e, Javas math.BigInteger/BigDecimal) which compute a bit slower but can take bigger numbers. Python does that "under the hood" for you - integers are always arbitraty big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Python manual's description on the representation of integers:

> These represent numbers in an unlimited range, subject to available (virtual) memory only. For the purpose of shift and mask operations, a binary representation is assumed, and negative numbers are represented in a variant of 2’s complement which gives the illusion of an infinite string of sign bits extending to the left.